# OGR FeatureCount returns '-1' with OSM data

Tags: python, gdal, openstreetmap, ogr

I am trying to read in an OSM file with OGR.

```
import ogr
driverOSM = ogr.GetDriverByName('OSM')
roadsDs = driverOSM.Open('data/map.osm', 0)
roadsLayer = roadsDs.GetLayer()
```

The feature count returns `-1`

```
print roadsLayer.GetFeatureCount()
```

When I loop over the features only points are returned, eventhough I know there are ways too (tested the data in QGIS).

```
featureStand = roadsLayer.GetNextFeature()
while featureStand:
  geomStand = featureStand.GetGeometryRef()
  print geomStand
  featureStand.Destroy()
  featureStand = roadsLayer.GetNextFeature()
```

Can anybody reproduce that or sees what I am doing wrong?

---

Python 2.7.5, GDAL 1.10.1, did not modify `osmconf.ini`

Comment: `-1` means [feature count not known](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRLayer.html#a74c796d4ce712e9a78df6042eeb8a91a)

Comment: @MikeToews, that makes sense. Still wondering why I `GetGeometryRef` only finds points.

Comment: There are other geometry types, but they are under different layers. Try `roadsLayer.GetLayerCount()` or possibly `roadsDs.GetLayer(3)` and you will see other geometry types.

Comment: That's interesting! `roadsLayer.GetLayerCount()` acutally gives me five layers. `GetLayer(0)` has the points and `GetLayer(1)` has the ways. Since I just used `GetLayer()` it chooesed the first layer (0) which are the points. Thanks @MikeToews! Do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [OSM file according to OGR](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_osm.html) contains five layers, one for each category:

1. **points** : "node" features that have significant tags attached.
2. **lines** : "way" features that are recognized as non-area.
3. **multilinestrings** : "relation" features that form a multilinestring(type = 'multilinestring' or type = 'route').
4. **multipolygons** : "relation" features that form a multipolygon (type = 'multipolygon' or type = 'boundary'), and "way" features that are recognized as area.
5. **other_relations** : "relation" features that do not belong to the above 2 layers.

The `GetLayer()` function actually takes a base-0 argument, so for the second layer, **lines**:

```
roadsLayer = roadsDs.GetLayer(1)
print(roadsLayer.GetName())  # lines
```

Although it isn't documented, it appears this driver is unable to get the feature count from a flat file, as `-1` means [feature count not known](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/classOGRLayer.html#a74c796d4ce712e9a78df6042eeb8a91a). Using a while-loop is probably the best way to go through the elements of each layer, as you have discovered.